# What client (java or rest) we should use for indexing the data in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have used java client for indexing my data in elastic search 1.4.4.
But now I am feeling, using java client is nightmare if we are doing the upgrade from 1.4.4 to newer version 2.3.2. If any one of you have used and let me know any benefits which is not possible using rest.

Comment: if you are using java client and want to do the smooth upgrade you can follow the below link.https://thejavaway.wordpress.com/2016/07/18/how-to-upgrade-elasticsearch

Comment: My solution was made in c# with help of this package: [link](https://damienbod.com/2014/09/22/elasticsearch-crud-net-provider/), also, you can try using the [nest](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) package provided by the elastic team. I recommend the first one if you want dynamic indexing combined with the use of reflection.

Comment: Elasticsearch 5.0 Alpha is changing how it operates to use a an HTTP/REST client as opposed to one that is so coupled.  If your need to upgrade isn't dire, part of me thinks it is almost worth it for you to wait until ES5 comes out of beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main benefit is performance. Java API is faster than Jest in the most cases. I would suggest to read this article [Interfacing with Elasticsearch: Picking a Client](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-interfacing-elasticsearch-picking-client) :

**Transport Client**

> It’s very fast and runs natively on the JVM. The serialization is
>   effective and there’s little to no overhead in messages and operations
>   sent to/from your Elasticsearch instances. It requires keeping the
>   Elasticsearch server and client versions somewhat synchronized. Prior
>   to Elasticsearch 1.0 the exact same versions would be required, but
>   newer versions (1.0 and later) support interacting between versions.
>   It’s also beneficial to run the same JVM update version on both the
>   clients and the servers due to exception serializing and other
>   potential minor differences between updates.

**Conclusion**

> It’s easy to spend a lot of time figuring out the differences between
>   the myriad of protocols and clients to use with Elasticsearch, but the
>   choice is actually pretty simple: if possible, use a high-performance
>   HTTP client that you are comfortable with or an official language
>   binding.
>
> If you’re using Java, the Transport client should be chosen over the
>   Node client unless the performance gain from using a Node client turns
>   out to be large enough to warrant the additional network complexity.
>   Use benchmarks to verify the performance gains.

I think this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876176/elasticsearch-jest-vs-rest-vs-transportclient-vs-nodeclient) would be useful too.

**PS**: I'll quote your question :

> if any one of you have used and let me know any benefits which is not
>   possible using rest.

Answer is performance. I realise that migration is really headache but you need to decide what more important for you: support or performance. For example Jest client is more functional than Java API and you can easily expand this functionality. You win in support but lose in speed. Read more  [Jest comparison to native API](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest#comparison-to-native-api):

> So if you have several ES clusters running different versions, then
>   using the native (or transport) client will be a problem, and you will
>   need to go HTTP (and Jest is the main option I think). If versioning
>   is not an issue, the native client will be your best option as it is
>   cluster aware

Comment: I understood the reason why should we use java client but my point is when we are upgrading to 1.4.4 to 2.3.2 lot of api changes happened and identifying the correct set of library is also challenging . In these cases maintenance will be nightmare everytime we are upgrading to newer version as ES is changing drastically in every release.

Comment: @AtulPratapSingh please have a look at PS section

Comment: Thanks alot  Vladislav Kysliy